# Trying to grab a character after a space in C

Tags: c, string, for-loop, cs50

For an assignment I am doing, I have to print out the initials from a string in C (or, an array of characters). To do this, I know that I need to find where the SPACE is, using (int)name[i] == 32 to find if the current character is a SPACE. My only issue with this is that I am having trouble figuring out how I can find the space, and then store the next character in the array of character. (e.g., user enters Mike Baggins, I have to print out MB). I will post my code below, to show you how far I've gotten. Please help, but please don't give me the full solution. Thank you!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string name = get_string(); // gets the user's input
    char firstI = name[0]; // stores the first character from the user's input
    int len = strlen(name);
    if((int)firstI >= 97 && (int)firstI <= 122) // checks if the character is lowercase
    {
        firstI -= 32; // makes the value uppercase
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if((int)name[i] == 32) // checks if the character is SPACE
        {
            printf("I found a space!\n"); // prints out "I found a space"
        }
    }
    printf("%c\n", firstI); // prints out the first initial
}
```

Comment: Why do you cast `name[i]`? Use `name[i] == ' '`! Also `for(int i = 0, len = strlen(name); i < len; i++)` indicates that you don't know how strings are represented in c.

Comment: There are handy and portable functions `islower` and `toupper` ...And you don't really need the first one.

Comment: What do you mean, "indicates you don't know how strings are represented". It's easy to use strlen() to get the full length of the string for analysis, so I simply used strlen().

Comment: @Nik see my answer please. Check in particular that I did not use `strlen()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually simple, see this for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char array[10];
    char string[] = "Mike Baggins";
    int j;
    // Always put the first non-whitespace 
    // character (we should probably skip all
    // spaces first
    array[0] = string[0];
    // Now start at the character following the first
    j = 1;
    for (int i = 1; ((string[i - 1] != '\0') && (j < sizeof(array) - 1)); ++i) {
        if (string[i - 1] == ' ') {
            array[j++] = toupper(string[i]);
        }
    }
    array[j] = '\0';
    puts(array);
    return 0;
}
```

All I needed was to know that strings are simply arrays with a special value marking the end of them → `'\0'`. Of course, you can improve it a lot. For instance, you could count how many initials are there in the input string and allocate enough space to store them all.

Also, this will only work if the interesting character follows the space immediately, but knowing that it's just an array I am sure you can figure out how to extend it to make it ignore consecutive spaces.

Comment: Interesting ... -1!

Comment: Ahh! I understand what you meant now! I did know that they were represented like that in memory, but I saw the entire string (including the white space marker (SPACE) as a string in itself and thought using '\0' would be pointless). Thank you! I will mess around with my program now, and see if I can get it to work. Thank you!

Comment: @Nik, even though it's a simple concept I find that many people learning c don't know it. Also, the idea is extensible to other kinds of objects like pointers, you can have a sequence of pointers ending with a `NULL` pointer and iterate the same way, in fact this is the idea behind linked lists.

Comment: Nohting is bad, and I mean -1 because someone downvoted the answer for no apparent reason. Using `strlen()` is ok and often necessay, but you should never do it in a loop like you did, specially if you are using an auxiliary variable `len` to store it's result. The reason is that `strlen()` is implemented in such a way that it iterates through the array and calculates it's length every time so it's inefficient.

Comment: @EOF besides, doesn't the compiler take care of such obvious optimisations?

Comment: Oh! I see what you mean. Well the reason I initialized it where I did, was to avoid the recursive initialization of the variable. If you notice, I declared and initialized the variable in the initializing section of the for loop (as you do for i), so that it only initializes once.

Comment: @Dunno Depends. In this case, yes, but in general, a `char *` can alias every other, so it can be difficult to prove that `strlen()` will be loop-invariant if an object of type `char` is modified in the loop.

Comment: @EOF you are right, it's just that it looked like `len = strlen(name), i < len`

Comment: @Dunno Also, it will then look like PHP code, just kidding. But I apologize for pointing that out since it is not present in the original code, that's when readability matters, I was completely mislead by the unusual syntax.

Comment: @Nik, just for readability do it before the loop, and only initialize `i` where you did. It's not important, both will be equivalent but it's confusing because it's harder to spot it.